# Try catch with multiple transaction - if failed, want to rollback both transactions on the catch

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I would like to encapsulate two transaction in one try catch clause.
the first transaction - insert to a table for the second transaction to read
and update or insert to a different table .

I've done it firstly on a single transaction, but it seems that i read uncommitted data so the result were incorrect.

the solution i've got right now, which is not good is to use two try catch for each transaction. The code is at the bottom

Is there a way to rollback two transaction if either of them fail?

```
 BEGIN TRY            
 BEGIN TRANSACTION             
  -- append to  DailyMovements new transactions              
                
   --INSERT INTO DailyMovements(MovementsDate,GCID,DailyMovmentsAmount,COIN,LastDailyTransactionCreated)              
   select lt.DailyMovementDate,lt.GCID,lt.DailyAmount,lt.HolderCurrency,lt.LastDailyTransactionCreated              
   FROM #NewTransactionAggregate lt              
   LEFT JOIN DailyMovements dm ON dm.GCID = lt.GCID   -- Left join for cases when there is no Movement day or GCID              
   AND dm.MovementsDate = lt.DailyMovementDate              
   ORDER BY MovementsDate                 
   
    COMMIT TRANSACTION             
 END TRY            
 BEGIN CATCH            
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0            
        ROLLBACK            
              
 DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int            
   SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),            
   @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()            
            
    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)            
 END CATCH            
            
   
   /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                
   EOD reCalculation for new transactions                
   1. New transaction for existing EODBalance date : update and recalculate EODBalance               
   2. New transactoin for new EODBalance date      : insert and recalculate EODBalance              
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/               
          
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#LastDailyMovementCreatedForGCID', 'U') IS NOT NULL                
  DROP TABLE #LastDailyMovementCreatedForGCID;           
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#NewDaily', 'U') IS NOT NULL                
  DROP TABLE #NewDaily;           
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#EODBalanceForNewTransaction', 'U') IS NOT NULL                
  DROP TABLE #EODBalanceForNewTransaction;           
   -- create table for GCID and calculate new EOD of transactions                  
  SELECT distinct   
   MovementsDate,      
   GCID,      
   SUM(DailyMovmentsAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY GCID,COIN ORDER BY MovementsDate ASC) AS EODBalanceAmount,      
   COIN,    
   max(LastDailyTransactionCreated) over(partition by GCID order by MovementsDate) as LastDailyMovementCreated    
  INTO #EODBalanceForNewTransaction      
  FROM DailyMovements dm      
  WHERE dm.GCID IN( SELECT DISTINCT nta.Gcid       
     FROM #NewTransactionAggregate nta)     
  
 BEGIN TRY            
 BEGIN TRANSACTION             
            
   -- 1) update EODBalance table with new transaction on existing date               
   --SELECT *--EODNewTran.MovementsDate,EODNewTran.GCID,EODNewTran.EODBalanceAmount,EODNewTran.COIN               
   update ce set ce.EODBalanceAmount = EODNewTran.EODBalanceAmount,ce.LastDailyMovementCreated = EODNewTran.LastDailyMovementCreated            
   FROM #EODBalanceForNewTransaction EODNewTran               
   inner JOIN CustomerEODBalance ce ON EODNewTran.GCID = ce.GCID AND  EODNewTran.MovementsDate = ce.EODBalanceDate AND  EODNewTran.COIN = ce.COIN              
   WHERE EODNewTran.EODBalanceAmount != ce.EODBalanceAmount              
              
   -- 2) insert new DailyMovement to EODBalance table               
   INSERT INTO CustomerEODBalance (EODBalanceDate,GCID,EODBalanceAmount,COIN,LastDailyMovementCreated)              
   SELECT EODNewTran.MovementsDate,EODNewTran.GCID,EODNewTran.EODBalanceAmount,EODNewTran.COIN,EODNewTran.LastDailyMovementCreated               
   FROM #EODBalanceForNewTransaction EODNewTran LEFT JOIN CustomerEODBalance ce ON EODNewTran.MovementsDate = ce.EODBalanceDate   and  EODNewTran.GCID = ce.GCID            
   WHERE ce.EODBalanceDate IS NULL              
   
 COMMIT TRANSACTION             
 END TRY            
 BEGIN CATCH            
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0            
        ROLLBACK            
              
 DECLARE @ErrMsg1 nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity1 int            
   SELECT @ErrMsg1 = ERROR_MESSAGE(),            
     @ErrSeverity1 = ERROR_SEVERITY()            
            
    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg1, @ErrSeverity1, 1)            
 END CATCH            
            
END
```

Comment: If you have two code blocks that need to either all commit or be rolled back then you want to put all of that code in a single transaction.

Comment: Please read Erland's discussion of tsql error handling - in particular how to [re-throw an error](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpTHROW)

Comment: I'm not even sure why this needs `TRY` `CATCH` as you aren't handling (logging) the error, just rolling back and rethrowing. Just use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` and remove all other error handling. This means the transaction will always be rolled back. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306846/what-is-the-point-of-try-catch-block-when-xact-abort-is-turned-on/306870#306870. Your existing error handling is broken in multiple ways: `RAISERROR` doesn't work if there are multiple errors. It also doesn't give the correct error number. And it doesn't abort the batch, so following code is still run

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want two operations to rollback together, you must enclose them in the same transaction.

Furthermore:

- Your `CATCH` and `ROLLBACK` and `RAISERRROR` handling is questionable for a number of reasons. Since you are not actually handling any error, you can remove all the error handling, and just use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` which will ensure a rollback in case of any error.
- What does the `LEFT JOIN` in the first statement do? It seems extraneous, as you don't select anything out of it, nor filter on it. Perhaps it was supposed to be an `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`.
- `DISTINCT` is unnecessary in a semi-join such as `IN (SELECT`
- `SUM ... OVER` should almost certainly have `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`.
- Why does that statement have an `ORDER BY`? Ordering makes little difference to an `INSERT` except when bulk-loading under specific circumstances.
- The final temporary table, `UPDATE` and `INSERT` could actually be a `MERGE`.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

  -- append to  DailyMovements new transactions              
                
INSERT INTO DailyMovements
  (MovementsDate, GCID, DailyMovmentsAmount, COIN, LastDailyTransactionCreated)              
select 
  lt.DailyMovementDate,
  lt.GCID,
  lt.DailyAmount,
  lt.HolderCurrency,
  lt.LastDailyTransactionCreated              
FROM #NewTransactionAggregate lt              
-- what does this LEFT JOIN do? It seems extraneous
LEFT JOIN DailyMovements dm ON dm.GCID = lt.GCID   -- Left join for cases when there is no Movement day or GCID              
   AND dm.MovementsDate = lt.DailyMovementDate              
ORDER BY MovementsDate;     -- why ORDER BY what does it help?
   

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                
   EOD reCalculation for new transactions                
   1. New transaction for existing EODBalance date : update and recalculate EODBalance               
   2. New transactoin for new EODBalance date      : insert and recalculate EODBalance              
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/               
          
;WITH EODBalanceForNewTransaction AS (
  SELECT distinct   
    MovementsDate,
    GCID,
    SUM(DailyMovmentsAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY GCID, COIN ORDER BY MovementsDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS EODBalanceAmount,
     COIN,
     max(LastDailyTransactionCreated) over (partition by GCID order by MovementsDate) as LastDailyMovementCreated
  FROM DailyMovements dm      
  WHERE dm.GCID IN (SELECT nta.Gcid       
     FROM #NewTransactionAggregate nta)     
)
MERGE CustomerEODBalance WITH (HOLDLOCK) ce
USING EODBalanceForNewTransaction EOD
   ON EOD.GCID = ce.GCID
  AND EOD.MovementsDate = ce.EODBalanceDate
  AND EOD.COIN = ce.COIN

WHEN MATCHED AND EOD.EODBalanceAmount != ce.EODBalanceAmount THEN
  UPDATE SET
    EODBalanceAmount         = EOD.EODBalanceAmount,
    LastDailyMovementCreated = EOD.LastDailyMovementCreated            
              
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT (EODBalanceDate, GCID, EODBalanceAmount, COIN, LastDailyMovementCreated)              
   VALUES (EOD.MovementsDate, EOD.GCID, EOD.EODBalanceAmount, EOD.COIN, EOD.LastDailyMovementCreated)
;

COMMIT TRAN;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and your detailed respond. As for the points: The left join is a mistake that i corrected. I saw the Rows unbound preceding is default, but i will add it to script. I would like to ask if there is a problem in the that the second DML (Update and Insert) is reading uncommited read (still in Begin Tran) made by the first query Insert???

Comment: No `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is the default, which is subtly different. Correct, because it's in the same transaction it can see all changes done by the previous command. This is quite normal, I'm not sure what else you would want. Only if you are running from a separate session then the transaction in this session prevents it from seeing uncommitted changes